# How to get a 'secret key' for on-demand revalidation ISR (nextjs)?

Tags: next.js

According to the documentation, you should use a SECRET_TOKEN to prevent unauthorized access to your revalidate API route i.e.

https://<your-site.com>/api/revalidate?secret=

Where do we generate a secret-token number? Or is this something we simply make up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need create your own secret key..

something like: 1LC@5lm2

url will be: https://your.website/api/revalidate?secret=1LC@5lm2&url=/page